# How to convert a list of strings to numbers or float?

Tags: python, string

I have an output like this:

```
0.4481696971
0.3993220707
0.4006741959
0.1333734337
0.9441898513
```

which is stored in a `result` variable.

What I'm trying to do is calculate the sum of all these lines and divide it by `number_lines` in this case 5. How could I achieve this?

```
values = [0.4, 0.0, 1.0, 0.25, 0.90]

print sum(values)
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? And, How are these numbers stored? `List` or file?

Comment: @moinuddin-quadri I edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: You have yet to answer the question, what is `type(result)`?  A list?

Comment: It's an api call request (for multiple tweets stored in a variable) printed in my console. I don't know what are you talking about.

Comment: I think it's a loop.

Answer (score 1):

(Edited)

You can first split `result` by `\n` and convert each of them to float. Then do whatever you want (average).

```
numbers = list(map(float, result.split("\n")))
print(sum(numbers))  # Sum.
print(sum(numbers) / len(numbers))  # Average.
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split', my numbers are in result variable, I changed result.split